# Dynamic svg xlink:href not rending the icons in browser

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg, vuejs2

I have a tab structure in Vue single file component where the icons are loaded using an svg sprite and dynamic variable inside the use component.

```html
<svg class="w-4 h-4 fill-current text-blue-500 mb-2 mx-auto">
<use class="h-4 w-4" :xlink:href="`@/assets/ui-icons.svg#${tab.name}`"></use>
</svg>
```

Result appears blank in Chrome and safari. The SVG doesnt get rendered, even though DEV tools shows compiled code exactly the way it should be.

[image: Still from Chrome Dev Tools]

Comment: Are you using Webpack?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under the assumption that you are using Webpack:

`@/assets/ui-icons.svg` is a relative URI, that is presumably processed by `resolve-url-loader` to resolve to the true URI of the SVG file when your website is transpiled. However, `resolve-url-loader` runs at transpile-time only, and here you have this URI inside of a Vue binding (`:xlink:href`), which is changed at run-time, and thus `resolve-url-loader` cannot fix it. Try doing this instead:

```html
<svg class="w-4 h-4 fill-current text-blue-500 mb-2 mx-auto">
  <use class="h-4 w-4" :xlink:href="require('@/assets/ui-icons.svg') + `#${tab.name}`"></use>
</svg>
```

The `require()` call will invoke `resolve-url-loader` and resolve to your SVG file, while the rest will link to the specific item in that SVG file that you want to reference. If you have other loaders specified for SVG then you will need to override them, like this:

> `require('!resolve-url-loader!@/assets/ui-icons.svg')`

Comment: Thank you so much @laptou. That trick worked and icons are now rendering as expected. Appreciated.